# Converting Java code to Scala code

Tags: java, scala

I want to convert the following Java code to Scala one:

```
Object method1(Object ... objArray) {
  if (objArray instanceof MyClass1[]) {
      Object resArray[] = new Object[objArray.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        resArray[i] = objArray[i].toString();
      }
      return resArray;
    } else {
      List<Object> resArray = new ArrayList<Object>();
      for (int i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++) {
        for (Object obj: scalar(objArray[i])) {
          resArray.add(obj);
        }
      }
      return resArray.toArray();
    }
  }

  //..........
  private static class MyClass1 {       
  private Object obj;

  public MyClass1(Object obj) {
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return obj.toString();
  }
 }
```

Here is what I have and it causes the errors:

```
def method1(objs: Any*): Array[_] = objs match {
    case x: Array[MyClass1] => x.map(toString)  // MyClass1 looks like 
    case x => x.map(method2).toArray
  }

//...................
def method2(obj: Any): Array[_] = {....} //it's perfectly fine

class MyClass1 (obj: AnyRef) {
    override def toString = obj.toString
}
```

errors:

```
1)pattern type is incompatible with expected type;
[error]  found   : Array[MyClass1]
[error]  required: Any*
[error]     case x: Array[MyClass1] => x.map(toString)

2)type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Array[MyClass1]
[error]  required: Any*
[error]     case x: Array[MyClass1] => x.map(toString)

3)could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type ClassManifest[Array[_]]
[error]     case x => x.map(method2).toArray
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Varargs**

Varargs in scala is `Seq`, not `Array`. So `objs` can't be an instance of `Array[MyClass1]`.

Actually you could get an `Array` like this:

```
def test(s: Any*) = s match {
  case wa: WrappedArray[_] => wa.array
  case _ => ???
}
```

But you'll get an `Array[_]`, not an `Array[MyClass1]`:

```
scala> test("a", "b", "c").isInstanceOf[Array[String]]
res0: Boolean = false
```

You could check all elements of `Array` and then convert `Array[_]` to `Array[MyClass1]`, but I don't think it's what you want:

```
scala> test("a", "b", "c") match {
     |   case a if a.forall{_.isInstanceOf[String]} => a.map{ case s: String => s }
     | }
res1: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c)
```

In this case you don't need an `Array`:

```
def method1(objs: Any*): Array[_] = objs match {
  case x if x.forall{_.isInstanceOf[MyClass1]} => x.map{_.toString}.toArray
  ...
}
```

**Manifest**

You should use [`Manifest`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.reflect.Manifest) here:

```
def test[T: Manifest](es: T*) = {
  if (implicitly[Manifest[T]] <:< implicitly[Manifest[MyClass1]])
    es.map{_.toString}.toArray
  else 
    x.flatMap(method2).toArray
}
```

`Manifest` is a workaround for type erasure, but you can't call such methods from `Java`.

**flatMap**

`Array[_]` is not a `Object[]`. You should replace `Array[_]` with `Array[Any]`.

With `x.map(method2).toArray` you'll get `Array[Array[Any]]`. I guess you want to get `Array[Any]` (as in your Java code), so you should use `flatMap` instead of `map` to aggregate all arrays.

**toString**

You are trying to pass function `toString` to method `map`:

```
x.map(toString)
```

There is no such function. You have to create one:

```
x.map{e => e.toString}
```

Or shorter:

```
x.map{_.toString}
```

Comment: and one more question: Is Scala's Any = Java's Object? I didn't find answer to this question, even though it seems like a very simple question.

Comment: `case x if x.forall{_.isInstanceOf[MyClass1]} => x.map{_.toString}.toArray` -- this is the fist and only condition? what about the second one?

Comment: @Grienders: In scala `AnyRef` === `Object`. But you could use `Any` in most cases.

Comment: `With x.map(method2).toArray you'll get Array[Array[Any]]` - why? it would be `Seq[Any]` -> `Array[Any]`.

Comment: @Grienders: see `Manifest` and `flatMap` parts for the second condition.

Comment: yes, I saw it, but it's still not clear. it looks like I should not use pattern matching at all.

Comment: @Grienders, if `x` is `Seq[Any]` and `method2` returns `Array[Any]` you'll get `Seq[Array[Any]]` after `x.map(method2)` (map transforms each element (`Any`) to result of function (`Array[Any]`)). And after `x.map(method2).toArray` you'll get `Array[Array[Any]]`

Comment: @Grienders: in this particular case pattern matching is useless.

Comment: you're right, I forgot about the return value of "method2" itself.

Comment: it gives me an error of `no type parameters for method flatMap: (f: T => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[B])(implicit bf: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Seq[T],B,That])That exist so that it can be applied to arguments (Any => scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[_])
[error]  --- because ---
[error] argument expression's type is not compatible with formal parameter type;
[error]  found   : Any => scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps[_]
[error]  required: T => scala.collection.GenTraversableOnce[?B]
[error]     else es.flatMap(method2).toArray`

Comment: @Grienders: do you still have any `Array[_]`?

Comment: nope. I only have this `def test[T: Manifest](es: T*) = {
  if (implicitly[Manifest[T]] <:< implicitly[Manifest[MyClass1]])
    es.map{_.toString}.toArray
  else 
    x.flatMap(method2).toArray
}`

Comment: @Grienders: I mean in the `method2` result type.

Comment: @Grienders: Try to replace it with `Array[Any]`

Comment: @Grienders: Or even with `Seq[Any]`

Comment: thanks, it's ok now. **In scala AnyRef === Object** aren't primitive objects in Java inherited from Object, likwise in Scala they are inherited from Any (Any<-- AnyVal)? If so, then Any should be equal to Object. If you have a link about this please give it me since I didn't find anything valuable which is odd.